# Rails 4 - Disable log per action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails application (4.2.4) which has an action which is invoked frequently so I have a a lot of extra log output. Is there a way to log anything (controller, action, parameters, complection time, etc.) for just this one action?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe this helps you

```
def method
  Rails.logger.silence do
    # this block is without logger stuff
  end
end
```

or further deep inside

http://dennisreimann.de/blog/silencing-the-rails-log-on-a-per-action-basis/

Comment: The whole routing request is better if there is a way.

Comment: then just look what dennisreimna.de posted. thats your way

Answer (score 0):

look at https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets - however I'm not sure if it works for your case.

Comment: but look whether it is possible to pass there another path regex, so it covers not only assets.

Comment: well yeah, he can make his own custom-silencer - thats true